# How to not use friend declaration when equipping a class with `operator<<`

Tags: c++

I understand that we'd want to do something like this to override `operator<<`

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
private:
    double m_x{};
    double m_y{};
    double m_z{};

public:
    Point(double x=0.0, double y=0.0, double z=0.0)
      : m_x{x}, m_y{y}, m_z{z}
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Point& point);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Point& point)
{
    // Since operator<< is a friend of the Point class, we can access Point's members directly.
    out << "Point(" << point.m_x << ", " << point.m_y << ", " << point.m_z << ')'; // actual output done here

    return out; // return std::ostream so we can chain calls to operator<<
}

int main()
{
    const Point point1{2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

    std::cout << point1 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

source: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/

But what if I don't need to access private member variables? I could continue to use `friend` but I'd prefer not to as in my opinion that would be confusing code. But I couldn't figure out how to not use `friend`. I tried:

1. Just dropping `friend`, but then the compiler would insert the implicit `this` pointer as the first argument, which is not what I want.
2. Changing `friend` to `static`, but my IDE complains that `operator<<` cannot be static.

Comment: Aside: it is idiomatic to have `friend std::ostream& operator<<`, because *conceptually* it is a member of `Point`, but *syntactically* can't be

Comment: I often make a public `void print(std::ostream&) const;` method in the class, then have the non-friend `<<` just forward the call `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Point const& pt) { pt.print(out); return out; }`.  Extra nice if there is polymorphism involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just declare `operator<<` as a free function in the same namespace as `Point` (in this case, the global namespace) and ADL will take care of it:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
   private:
    double m_x{};
    double m_y{};
    double m_z{};

   public:
    Point(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0, double z = 0.0)
        : m_x{x}, m_y{y}, m_z{z} {}

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point& point) {
    out << "Point";
    // Use public interface of point here.
    return out;
}

int main() {
    const Point point1{2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

    std::cout << point1 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Same example, less code:

```
class Point
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Point& point);  // 1
};


// 2
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Point& point)
{    
    return out;
}
```

`//1` is just declaring that `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Point&);` is a `friend` of the class. Thats all this line means. If you do not want to declare the function as a friend of the class then remove this line:

```
class Point {};


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Point& point)
{
    // only access to public members of point
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks! Marking the @paolo answer as right as it feels a little more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to solve this:

1. make m_x, m_y, m_z public
2. add public x, y, z methods that return m_x, m_y, m_z
3. add public print method that the operator << can call

Comment: Thanks. I think the accepted answer better understood what I was asking. In my case, the member variables I want to access are public already, and I just wanted to know how to best overload `operator<<` in that case. Sorry if I was unclear at all.

Comment: I think it's a little extreme making member variable public just so you can print them out. It sort of negates a lot of the benefits of classes to expose their internals that way.

Comment: For a point where the structure is a known construct and every bit pattern is valid there is no benefit to hiding the members. I usually just define mathematical constructs such as vectors and matrixes as structs with everything public. But yeah, it's extreme. So don't use it and go with option 2 or 3. They are ranged in order of privacy, least to most.